# Sandbox paypal not returning success in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated sandbox paypal into my application.After successful payment i am not getting success in the query string.Instead i get is return to merchant but if i do cancel i get the cancel in the query string

Comment: hello, did you solve the problem yet, i am having problem getting the paypal automated license generation to work

Answer (score 0):

Are you verifying the IPN notification with Paypal?

Comment: I think thats required. When you receive a IPN notification, you must callback to the PayPal servers to verify the notification. This is described in the docs for IPN.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, @logicnp, this would be better as a comment and not an answer.